# a way to Tone down/ fix an image to prevent darkening/ bluring if shrinked

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, photoshop-effects

I am trying to make a customized keychain using shrink plastic (anyone familiar with shrinky dinks? ) 
I use an inkjet printer to print directly on the shrink plastic
I noticed that after baking, after the shrink plastic shrinks, the image becomes darker and somewhat blurred.
This Process is like shrinking a picture in photoshop.
Is there a way, lets say edit in photoshop to prevent darkening.

Comment: It's the physical materials that you'd need to change, to prevent it from getting darker. You could try making it lighter in photoshop, so that when it gets darker, it would look more normal, but you can't use photoshop to prevent it getting dark.

Comment: @Joonas Thanks for your comment, I really don't know  how to properly explain this because i am not that good in photoshop. btw thanks for your suggestion I'll try to make it lighter in photoshop and see what happens.

Comment: @Joonas I have read about images getting "tone down". How do you tone down an image?

Comment: There are many ways. I'd perhaps start from [Brightness and contrast adjustment](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/apply-brightness-contrast-adjustment.html).

Answer (score 1):

You must have in mind that by thermically shrinking something printed, you will get a much bigger **dot gain** issue, the darker is the color (more K / black ink) more prone to dot gain it is. So there's some things you could do to avoid color distortion:

Photoshop has **Proof Settings** that can let you preview a possible color distortion due to printing / color blindness whilst you edit the picture looking at its desired values onscreen.

Being aware of this, this is what you can base yourself on the miscolored print, open your image and adjust proof settings so the proof colors match the colors of the darker shrinked print, once they match, you can then distort colors the original in a way it will look correct on the proof view. You can alternate between proof and standard with `CTRL` + `Y` or creating a new view for your document.

Blurring may be an issue from the melting process, for that i guess that applying multiple sharpen filters to it may soothen the effects of the melting, for this is a bit of trial and error.